# How to set an inverse relationship in XCode

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4.5

This is a silly question, but I seriously didn't find an answer...

I have a one-to-many relationship from the Entity `Events` to `Discounts` and I set a relationship like this in Xcode:

[image]

I need that relationship to be inverse, so I can check which `Event` a `Discount` is from, but in XCode I can only choose "No Inverse."  How can I set that relationship to be inverse?!

If you have to do it programatically, first, seriously?  It can't be done from XCode?  Secondly, how can I do it?  And where should this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to set inverse relationship you need to create it first in destination entity.

So in Discounts entity create relationship to Event that you want to use as reverse (e.g. `event`), then you will be able to choose it as reverse for your toDiscounts relationship

Comment: Ah, one question, so when I try access the Event from Discount I have to something like [discount valueForKey:@"toEvent"] or [discount valueForKey:@"toDiscount"] ? or both are good?

Comment: You can use discount.toEvent property  or [discount valueForKey:@"toEvent"]